# Getting "Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups" on every received email

Tags: email, exchange, office365, smtp, outlook-web-access

in Office 365 I recently converted an email address from a shared mailbox to a user mailbox, but I've noticed that every time we receive an email to that address (even though we DO actually receive it), we get another email seconds later saying the following:

'Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups'
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: HE1P191MB0137.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=99247ae283514c3a9f35f67f189741af-jenny@EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
Remote Server returned '550 5.2.0 RESOLVER.ADR.MissingPrimary; recipient primary SMTP address is missing: '''

Original message headers:

Authentication-Results: spf=permerror (sender IP is 209.85.223.178)
 smtp.mailfrom=accounts@stadavideo.co.uk; 
Received: from HE1P191MB0203.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.172.128.140) by
 HE1P191MB0137.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.172.128.15) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.820.15; Tue, 5 Jun 2018 10:46:53 +0000
Received: from HE1P191MB0203.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM ([::1]) by
 HE1P191MB0203.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM ([fe80::7558:2d5c:f145:3f73%10]) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server id 15.20.0820.015; Tue, 5 Jun 2018 10:46:53 +0000
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Sending emails seems to work fine, as I've tested both internally & externally. It looks like this was happening before I changed the email over to a user mailbox too, but nobody noticed.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the NDR, it looks the primary SMTP address is invalid or missing. You may first run the following command and see whether the SMTP address is valid:

get-mailbox  | fl *email*

Answer (score 0):

When you get an NDR with IMCEAEX- , it means the X500 address is missing from the recipient, to decode the record, please go through the URL and then implement the same on:

IMCEAEX-_o=ExchangeLabs_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=99247ae283514c3a9f35f67f189741af-jenny@EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

Please find the URL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/mail-delivery/imceaex-ndr